# grab par values without opening a graphics device

Tags: r

Is it possible to grab the parameters from par without opening the graphics device?  So for instance if I do:

```
opar <- par()[["mar"]]
opar
```

on my windows 7/linux mint 14/mac machines a graphics device is opened.

How can I grab the output without awakening the graphics device?

Comment: what `r` interpreter are you using?

Comment: I am ignorant as to what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the parameters from `par()` are stored as a part of the graphics device.

**Details**

`par()` calls an internal c function (`C_par()`) that checks the current device using the c function `GEcurrentDevice()` which asks for the current device.  If it cannot find a device, it starts one ([source code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/e242a7ebfb1b9921b29e2c5f88411f5018b0f74f/src/main/devices.c)).  `C_par()` then adds the parameters to the device using the `Query()` function ([source code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/56becd21c75d104bfec829f9c23baa2e144869a2/src/library/graphics/src/par.c)).