# Obtain standardised residuals and "Residual v.s. Fitted" plot for "mlm" object from `lm()`

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, mlm

```
set.seed(0)
## 2 response of 10 observations each
response <- matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2)
## 3 covariates with 10 observations each
predictors <- matrix(rnorm(30), 10, 3)
fit <- lm(response ~ predictors)
```

I have been generating residual plots for the entire model using:

```
plot(fitted(fit),residuals(fit))
```

However, I would like to make individual plots for each predictor covariate. I can do them one at a time by:

```
f <- fitted(fit)
r <- residual(fit)
plot(f[,1],r[,1])
```

The issue with this approach however, is that it needs to be generalizable for data sets with more predictor covariates. Is there a way that I use plot while iterating through each column of (f) and (r)? Or is there a way that `plot()` can group each co-variate by colour?

Comment: not really clear what your are trying to do. e.g. `rnorm(20)` did you actually mean `rnorm(1:20)`? what is in the `fit`? try `sammary(fit)` for your code and explain it.

Comment: Thought I was pretty clear, and provided reproducible code. Fit is the linear model.

Comment: Well, that reproducible code generates same values in all columns. Reproducible code that does not do what you think it is doing is not helpful.

Comment: It doesn't matter though. The contents of the matrices is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: what is the point of the code than? make a proper example using existing dataset, e.g. `data("iris")` , `head(iris)`. fitting matrix to matrix does not make much sense to me.

Comment: What exactly is unclear about my question? I'm plotting fitted values for a model against their residuals. I'm asking how to programmatically do this for each column is a fitted() and residuals() summary.

Comment: `response <- matrix(rnorm(1:20),20,200)` what is this? vector of independent values? should it it be just `rnorm(1:20)`?

Comment: why do you think it's important in order to help answer my question? my question is about plot(), not about some philosophical discussion about rnorm()

Comment: @forder You could check [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lm) posts

Comment: Sure, you're more than welcome to comment or provide an answer. The question was downvoted because some people would prefer to be pedantic rather than helpful. I know, I don't get it either. It's a relatively straight forward question, and from what I understand (admittedly not a lot) is particularly important in assessing training error for linear models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make Sure you are using standardised residuals rather than raw residuals**

I often see `plot(fitted(fit), residuals(fit))` but it is statistically wrong. We use `plot(fit)` to generate diagnostic plot, **because we need standardised residuals rather than raw ones.** Read `?plot.lm` for more. But `plot` method for "mlm" is poorly supported:

```
plot(fit)
# Error: 'plot.mlm' is not implemented yet
```

---

**Define "rstandard" S3 method for "mlm"**

`plot.mlm` is not supported for many reasons, one of which is the lack of `rstandard.mlm`. For "lm" and "glm" class, there is a generic S3 method "rstandard" to get standardised residuals:

```
methods(rstandard)
# [1] rstandard.glm* rstandard.lm*
```

There is no support for "mlm". So we shall fill this gap first.

It is not difficult to get standardised residuals. Let `hii` be diagonals of the hat matrix, the point-wise estimated standard error for residuals is `sqrt(1 - hii) * sigma`, where `sigma = sqrt(RSS / df.residual)` is estimated residual standard error. `RSS` is residual sum of squares; `df.residual` is residual degree of freedom.

`hii` can be computed from matrix factor `Q` of QR factorization of model matrix: `rowSums(Q ^ 2)`. For "mlm", there is only one QR decomposition since the model matrix is the same for all responses, hence we only need to compute `hii` once.

Different response has different `sigma`, but they are elegantly `colSums(residuals(fit) ^ 2) / df.residual(fit)`.

Now, let's wrap up those ideas to get our own "rstandard" method for "mlm":

```
## define our own "rstandard" method for "mlm" class
rstandard.mlm <- function (model) {
  Q <- with(model, qr.qy(qr, diag(1, nrow = nrow(qr$qr), ncol = qr$rank)))  ## Q matrix
  hii <- rowSums(Q ^ 2)  ## diagonal of hat matrix QQ'
  RSS <- colSums(model$residuals ^ 2)  ## residual sums of squares (for each model)
  sigma <- sqrt(RSS / model$df.residual)  ##  ## Pearson estimate of residuals (for each model)
  pointwise_sd <- outer(sqrt(1 - hii), sigma)  ## point-wise residual standard error (for each model)
  model$residuals / pointwise_sd  ## standardised residuals
  }
```

Note the use of `.mlm` in function name to tell R this is S3 method associated. Once we have defined this function, we can see it in "rstandard" method:

```
## now there are method for "mlm"
methods(rstandard)
# [1] rstandard.glm* rstandard.lm*  rstandard.mlm
```

To call this function, we don't have to explicitly call `rstandard.mlm`; calling `rstandard` is enough:

```
## test with your fitted model `fit`
rstandard(fit)
#          [,1]       [,2]
#1   1.56221865  2.6593505
#2  -0.98791320 -1.9344546
#3   0.06042529 -0.4858276
#4   0.18713629  2.9814135
#5   0.11277397  1.4336484
#6  -0.74289985 -2.4452868
#7   0.03690363  0.7015916
#8  -1.58940448 -1.2850961
#9   0.38504435  1.3907223
#10  1.34618139 -1.5900891
```

Standardised residuals are `N(0, 1)` distributed.

---

**Getting residuals v.s. fitted plot for "mlm"**

Your initial try with:

```
f <- fitted(fit); r <- rstandard(fit); plot(f, r)
```

is not a bad idea, provided that dots for different models can be identified from each other. So we can try using different point colours for different models:

```
plot(f, r, col = as.numeric(col(f)), pch = 19)
```

Graphical arguments like `col`, `pch` and `cex` can take vector input. I ask `plot` to use `col = j` for the `r[,j] ~ f[,j]`, where `j = 1, 2,..., ncol(f)`. Read "Color Specification" of `?par` for what `col = j` means. `pch = 19` tells `plot` to draw solid dots. Read [basic graphcial parameters](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html) for various choices.

Finally you may want a legend. You can do

```
plot(f, r, col = as.numeric(col(f)), pch = 19, ylim = c(-3, 4))
legend("topleft", legend = paste0("response ", 1:ncol(f)), pch = 19,
       col = 1:ncol(f), text.col = 1:ncol(f))
```

In order to leave space for the legend box we extend `ylim` a little bit. As standardised residuals are `N(0,1)`, `ylim = c(-3, 3)` is a good range. Should we want to place the legend box on the top left, we extend `ylim` to `c(-3, 4)`. You can customize your legend even more via `ncol`, `title`, etc.

[image]

---

**How many responses do you have?**

If you have no more than a few responses, above suggestion works nicely. If you have plenty, plotting them in separate plot is suggested. A `for` loop as you found out is decent, except that you need split plotting region into different subplots, possibly using `par(mfrow = c(?, ?))`. Also set inner margin `mar` and outer margin `oma` if you take this approach. You may read [How to produce a nicer plot for my categorical time series data in a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39020435/4891738) for one example of doing this.

If you have even more responses, you might want a mixture of both? Say if you have 42 responses, you can do `par(mfrow = c(2, 3))`, then plot 7 responses in each subfigure. Now the solution is more opinion based.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I solved it.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(f)) {
    plot(f[,i],r[,i])
}
```

Mind blown.

Comment: You are getting a plot for each response variable here. Again your code is not doing what you think it is, or your question was wrong.

Comment: @forder I think this is a comment and not an answer.